# Sorting in Powershell except few output

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have multiple services. Suppose i starts with A . When I execute

`Get-Service A*` - It will display services as output starting with A.

I am sorting complete output except one and want that to be on top of my list once sorted. I am using below command.

```
Get-Service -DisplayName A* |Sort-Object {$_.Name -ne 'AK'}
```

It is listing all output in sorted way and **AK** is on top Like below .

```
AK
AN
AR
AS
```

and so on . This is only keeping AK on top and sorting others. I want to do same thing for 2 services. AK and then AR(suppose)- This both should be always in AK and AR order at top then other services need to sort. How to add this in existing code for **AR**.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `-notin` Operator, you can specify an array of excludes:

```
Get-Service A* | Sort-Object {$_.name -notin "AK","AR"}
```

This way the AK and AR service will be on top of the sorted list

EDIT: for V2 simple and easy:

```
Get-Service A* | Sort-Object {"AK","AR" -notcontains $_.name}
```

Comment: When running it is saying "You must provide a value expression on the right-side of the '-' operator"

Comment: What powershell version are you on?

Comment: I have v2 in some machine and v4 in some machine. -ne was working on both for 1 to exclude .

Answer (score 1):

You need -notin and ():

```
'AK','AN','AR','AS' | sort {$_ -notin ('AN', 'AS')}
```

Or with PS 2.0:

```
'AK','AN','AR','AS' | sort {[Array]::IndexOf(('AN', 'AS'), $_) -eq -1}
```

Or (thanks to @Mathias):

```
'AK','AN','AR','AS' | sort {('AN', 'AS') -notcontains $_}
```

Comment: I added V2 script.

Comment: You could use `-notcontains` as well: `sort { ('AN', 'AS') -notcontains $_ }`